# sobre escritura de metodos

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código y cuando intento sobre escribir el método `rellenarTipo` me da error,he creado una clase principal llamada `main` y otra clase llamada `subclase` que hereda de `main` donde al poner `@Override` es cuando me indica error

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rellenarTipo();
    }
    public static void rellenarTipo() {
        String dni, nombre;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("introduza nombre");
        nombre = scan.next();
        System.out.println("introduzca dni");
        dni = scan.next();
    }
}
```

Y esta es la subclase que hereda de la clase `main` y donde quiero sobre escirbir rellenar tipo, alguien me guia un poco para saber que hago mal?

```
public class SubClase extends main {
    int edad;
    @Override
    public static void rellenarTipo(){
        System.out.println("introduzca edad");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Java, los métodos estáticos `static` **no pueden ser sobreescritos** puesto que los miembros estáticos le pertenecen a la clase, no a las instancias de la clase. Debes declarar métodos no estáticos para ello.

Tu clase debería lucir así:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main m = new main();
        m.rellenarTipo();
    }
    public void rellenarTipo() {
        String dni, nombre;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("introduza nombre");
        nombre = scan.next();
        System.out.println("introduzca dni");
        dni = scan.next();
    }
}

public class SubClase extends main {
    int edad;
    @Override
    public void rellenarTipo() {
        System.out.println("introduzca edad");
    }
}
```

Asimismo, si quieres guardar datos para tu clase, estos no deberían ser variables locales a los métodos, sino deben ser campos de la clase. Entonces, el diseño de tus clases debería quedar así:

```
public class main {
    String dni, nombre;
    protected static Scanner scan;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main m = new Subclase();
        m.rellenarTipo();
    }
    public void rellenarTipo() {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("introduza nombre");
        this.nombre = scan.next();
        System.out.println("introduzca dni");
        this.dni = scan.next();
    }
}

public class SubClase extends main {
    int edad;
    @Override
    public void rellenarTipo() {
        System.out.println("introduzca edad");
        this.edad = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: De nada. He agregado más contenido para que tu clase tenga mejor diseño.

Comment: Ahora ya lo he entendido,que tengas un buen dia ;)